# sprintf and % signs in text

Tags: php, printf

A problem I recently ran into was that when trying to update a field in my database using this code would not work. I traced it back to having a `%` sign in the text being updated (`$note`, then `$note_escaped`)... Inserting it with `sprintf` worked fine though.

Should I not be using `sprintf` for updates, or should it be formed differently?

I did some searching but couldn't come up with anything.

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$note_escaped = mysql_real_escape_string($note);
$editedby = mysql_real_escape_string($author);
$editdate = mysql_real_escape_string($date);
//insert info from form into database
$query= sprintf("UPDATE notes_$suffix SET note='$note_escaped', editedby='$editedby', editdate='$editdate' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Thanks everyone: What really tripped me up when I took the actual query and stuck it in Sequel Pro and ran it- it updated the database properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using sprintf totally wrong. Removing the function call in your code would still do the same thing. It should be:

```
sprintf("UPDATE notes_%s SET note='%s', editedby='%s', editdate='%s' WHERE id=%d LIMIT 1", $suffix, $note_escaped, $editedby, $editdate, $id);
```

You should read the manual.

Answer (score 3):

first of all you should be using [prepared statements](http://mattbango.com/notebook/web-development/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/) instead of a sprintf-call

but if you absolutely have to do it this way you have to use:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$note_escaped = mysql_real_escape_string($note);
$editedby = mysql_real_escape_string($author);
$editdate = mysql_real_escape_string($date);
//insert info from form into database
$query= sprintf("
  UPDATE notes_%s /* this is still open for injection, and cannot be properly escaped with mysql_real_escape_string */
  SET note='%s', 
  editedby='%s', 
  editdate='%s' 
  WHERE id='%d'
  LIMIT 1",
$suffix,
$note_escaped, $editedby, $editdate, $id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the `%` in the source text by replacing it with  `\%` in mysql.

Comment: The correct way to escape in mysql is \% - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

sprintf() is not used much in PHP, unless you need to format data somehow. These two statements work identically in PHP:

```
$num = 42;
$char = 'q';

$text = sprintf('The number is %d and the character is %s', $num, $char);
$text = "The number is $num and the character is $char";
```

sprintf's used more in C for "printing" variable data into a string. But PHP can already do that with double-quoted strings, so unless you need to use sprintf's special formatting functions (e.g. `%0.2f` for a 2-decimal-place float), it's easier to use the regular string method.

Comment: hell will freeze over if you create sql-strings with variable substitution in double quoted strings

Comment: Building queries manually is only dangerous if you're unaware of SQL injection, and/or don't care. Screaming that manual queries are dangerous from the rooftops doesn't help to educate beginners.

Comment: It seems that I read something somewhere that sprintf() was a faster way to execute mysql queries than a normal variable string.

Comment: Nope. Double-quoted strings are actually much much faster. There's no format parsing overhead: http://judebert.com/progress/archives/204-PHP-String-Formatting-Performance.html

Answer (score -1):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php:

**Note: mysql_real_escape_string() does not escape % and _. These are wildcards in MySQL if combined with LIKE, GRANT, or REVOKE.**

You need to manually escape the % and _ if any with \% and _. I don't recommend using sprintf, but just improving your escape function.